# Yii2 check existance combination of three fields of model in beforeSave() and update(or insert)

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I'm tring to check duplicate data  in beforeSave function. But It's not working properly: There is my beforeSave function body :

```
$duplicate=self::find()->where(["u_id"=>$this->attributes["u_id"],"link_doc_id"=>$this->attributes["link_doc_id"],"link_doc_type"=>$this->attributes["link_doc_type"]])->one();
        if($duplicate){
            $insert=false;
            $this->or_id=$duplicate->or_id;
        }
```

But i'm getting duplicate `Integrity constraint violation error`. I know that i'm doing wrong when i manually set `$this->or_id`. So how to check duplicate data in database.
My validation rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['reorder', 'link_doc_id', 'u_id', 'period', 'close_doc_id', 'close_uid'], 'integer'],
            [['create_date', 'deadline', 'close_date', 'view','description' ], 'safe'],
            [['close_description'], 'string'],
            [['link_doc_type', 'close_doc_type'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
            [['desc'], 'string', 'max' => 50]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: please give your `model` code

Comment: You should use validation rules for this purpose.

Comment: @ineersa how can do valdation rule for that three fields must be unique together same  time

Comment: @vishu which part of this model u need , i will post you, because a lot of codes  there are

Comment: you just define `[['u_id'], 'unique']` in your model rules()

Comment: But should be  u_id, link_doc_id and link_doc_type fields unique together (same time) not only one of them or two of them

Comment: add this to check all unique at same time `[['u_id', 'link_doc_id', 'link_doc_type'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['u_id', 'link_doc_id', 'link_doc_type'], 'message' => 'Error Message hear']`

Comment: @vishu thanks. but this not resolve my problem. As you can see there is your rule check separatly check unique vaidation for every fields. But i need the combination of these three columns must be unique. not one of the

Comment: now you change this three `'u_id', 'link_doc_id', 'link_doc_type'` field as unique in your database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98076/discussion-between-vishu-and-nuriddin-rashidov).

Comment: I already did that with help of this query alter table Variable_Entries add unique (u_id, link_doc_id,link_doc_type); There are unique combination. But i think in yii not checking for this and execute query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add In your model `'u_id', 'link_doc_id', 'link_doc_type'` unique validation like...

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['reorder', 'link_doc_id', 'u_id', 'period', 'close_doc_id', 'close_uid'], 'integer'],
        [['create_date', 'deadline', 'close_date', 'view','description' ], 'safe'],
        [['close_description'], 'string'],
        [['link_doc_type', 'close_doc_type'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['desc'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['u_id', 'link_doc_id', 'link_doc_type'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['u_id', 'link_doc_id', 'link_doc_type'], 'message' => 'Error Message hear']
    ];
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of the rule for the OP and other users to make the answer complete.

Comment: I'm sorry i will this now